# Data annotation to do rounding

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations

Hi I have a property in one of my models which is:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Total (Exc. GST) is a required field.")]
[Display(Name = "Total (Exc. GST):")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public virtual decimal TotalExcludingGst { get; set; }
```

It has the currency annotation above it.

The problem is  when an issue with it happened during validation it displays with 4 decimal places like

57500.0000

Is there anyway to add an annotation that will make this 2 decimal places in the validation messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}")]
```

or

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
```